# Connection to MongoDB URI is failing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect my MongoDB URI, but have run into a couple errors.  First error, was "EADDRINUSE" error that send my port number was already in use, so I ran the Command Prompt (I'm on Windows) as Administrator, and used taskkill -f on the Port.  Now I'm no longer getting the "EADDRINUSE" error, however I am failing to connect to my MongoDB database.  How do I resolve this?

Server File
[image]

Database Connection File
[image]

Comment: You PC is "Ariplane Mode". This turn off all wireless communications on your PC. Also is not a good idea to share your <username> and <password>.

Comment: Are you sure you have your mongo server on and running?

Comment: The result is just a string of 'MongoDB Connection Failed'.  I also tried turning off the Airplane Mode but it still won't connect.

Comment: I believe so, I have set up my port, and the server itself seems to be listening and responding.  It's the database connection to MongoDB that doesn't seem to be working.